# Copy Process for Azure Boards from one organization to other organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

After building up a customized inherited process in Azure DevOps, how can I copy this process to an other organization?

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool that developed by Microsoft: [VSTS Process Migrator](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator).

- Install it:

  ```
  npm install process-migrator -g
  ```
- Create a config file according to the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator#documentation).
- Run the tool:

  ```
  process-migrator --mode=migrate(default)/imoport/export --config=<config-file-path>
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I will try the approach after the summer vacation.